# Replacing a string at a particular positiion

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with Name at position 0-10, phone at 11-20.

How can I replace a string at location 11 to contain all 9's?

I've been playing around with `Get-Content` and `-replace` to get familiar.

```
$path = "g:\test.txt"
(Get-Content $path) -replace "Name", "Forename" | Out-File $path
```

Example :

```
STARTDELIV|BA|BATCH PRINT               |
INFORMAT01|email@address.com            |
INFORMAT02|01021990|CRZWS|AA|2          |
INFORMAT03|Mr. John Doe|+00000          |
```

So say I would like to replace the name Mr. John Doe with X's , how would I prevent it replacing the same 10 bytes on every line

Comment: `-replace '^(.{11}).{10}', '${1}99999999999'`

Comment: Thanks! If I have multiple lines in the text file for example.
Name|Number
DOB|Email
How can I prevent the next lines being changed to 9's

Comment: You need to make the match more specific. Please provide sample input.

Comment: ADDRDETAIL
STARTDELIV
PRODUCTDE
BILINGDATAS
PLCYCLIENT
BENEFITPRO

For example that is my text file. If I would like to change BENEFITPRO to ORPTIFENEB how could I. Basically to change that text without affecting other lines.

Comment: So you want to replace the name, not the number? Could you please clarify, and also update your question with a representative sample of your input data? Sensitive information may be obfuscated, but the sample should reflect the actual structure of your data.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the original message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `SubString` method to get the 10 characters of the string starting from position 11:

```
$Path = "g:\test.txt"
$String = (Get-Content $Path)     
$StringToReplace = $String.Substring(11,10)
```

And then use `-Replace` to replace that part of the string with all 9s (beware this assumes that string doesn't occur in that way anywhere else in the string):

```
$String -Replace $StringToReplace,('9'*$StringToReplace.Length)
```

Here's a shorter single line way to achieve the same result:

```
$String.Replace($String.Substring(11,10),'9'*10)
```

Comment: I don't seem to be getting this to work. Cannot call a method on a null-valued expression
$StringToReplace = $String.Substring(11,10)

Comment: I've added in your code to get the file contents. Does that help?

Comment: It is saying there is an issue with the $String - Replace
*************
 $Path = "g:\test\ABS.SVD"
$String = (Get-Content $Path)     
$StringToReplace = $String.Substring(11,10)
$String -Replace $StringToReplace,('9'*$StringToReplace.Length)

Comment: Check `$String` has the content you expect it to after doing your `Get-Content` command.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that, sorry?

Comment: Just execute this: `$Path = "g:\test\ABS.SVD"; 
$String = (Get-Content $Path);
$String` and check the output is what you expect.

Comment: It seems to be, it is taking in the file and running succesfully.

Comment: The code assumes you want to do the replace on every line of the file and that every line of the file is at least 22 characters long. If that is not the case you will see an error. If that is not what you intended, you might need to clarify your question.

Comment: Yes every line is more than 22 characters long, I have it working on the above users comment but yours seems more detailed and as a new learner I wanted to get a different option (out of curiousity) thanks